# Using Kafka & Zookeeper, Different group id does not retrieve Kafka msgs from the beginning

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

We have kafka v2.10 and zookeeper v3.4 set up and working. We have written high level consumers consuming log msgs from Kafka.  Consumer A starts up consuming msgs for topic T and group id G1 (following the high level consumer example provided on Apache Kafka documentation).
Then when consumer B starts up with the same topic T but group id G2, it connects to kafka/zookeeper, but consumes log msgs starting with the offset after the last one used by Consumer A.

My understanding is that it should be given log msgs starting with the lowest offset available in Kafka for that topic.  Any idea why it's not doing that?

We are not replicating kafka or zookeeper yet. OUr set up at this point is simple and straight forward and we are trying to get them to work with basic functionality.

Any help is appreciated.

Also, do you know where we can locate the new directories that supposedly zookeeper is creating everytime a consumer with a new group id establishes connection with the zookeeper (for tracking offset for that group id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try adding this to the configuration while creating the Consumer group

```
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it.  Do you know how in zookeeper client I can display the last offset a consumer groupid has read for a topic.  It must be saving it someplace for it to know the next offset with which that consumer groupid shoudl start with.

Comment: I would suggest you put a separate question for this .. but before that go through http://kafka.apache.org/08/documentation.html#distributionimpl to have a basic understanding of how zookeeper is involved in this